# How to change Chart background color in PhpPresentation?

Tags: phppresentation

I know how to change background color in slide,
but i can't find how to change background color in chart.

[Default Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8u0V.jpg)

I use a default code from PhpPresentation

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer!

just use this code :

```
$shape->getFill()->setFillType(Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR)
      ->setRotation(90)
      ->setStartColor(new Color('FF000000'))
      ->setEndColor(new Color('FFB1B1B1'));
```

Below this code

```
$shape->setFill($oFill);
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).